The resource calendar is not updating based on attendees' responses(accept,declined,tentative) in Exchange
I created a meeting in Outlook and invited participants. I am monitoring the resource calendar through Graph subscriptions. The meeting synced to my application when I received the create notification from the resource calendar.
When I update the meeting, I receive the update notification and am able to make the necessary changes in my system.
However, when any participant accepts or declines the meeting, I do not receive an update event because the resource calendar is not being updated. How can I resolve this issue?
I tried changing the resource properties but was not successful in achieving my goal
